# how to use links returning paginate to JSON response in AJAX LARAVEL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-pagination

How can I use or call  $data->links() for pagination. In my scenario, I'm using get request using AJAX JavaScript. It return a JSON Response and I want to call $data->links() using JavaScript.

this is my Controller

```
public function getOrders($store_id)
{
    $data = DB::table('stores')
    ->where('stores.id',$store_id)
    ->paginate(5);

    return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
}
```

This is my Get Request AJAX

```
function fetchOrder(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/get-orders/"+store_id,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {

                if (response.data.data != null) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $('.OrderTbody').html("");
                    $.each(response.data.data, function (key, item) {
                        $('.OrderTbody').append('<tr><td>' + item.store_name + '</td></tr>');

                    });


                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: You can't call `$data->links()` because the response is no longer a collection. But if you view the response (which I see you're logging in the console), then you can see that there is a links property in the response that you can use.

Comment: yes I can see it, I tried to console.log  using response.data.links and it gave me this response (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] inside that , all url, but I dont know how to use it please help sir @aynber

Comment: Links is an array of objects, so you'll need to iterate through it just like you did with `response.data.data`. (By the way, not everyone on the internet, or SO for that matter, is a "sir")

Comment: You need to add a page parameter to your current fetchOrder function, and call it using page parameter. if you take a look at your pagination links, they should be the same link you're fetching but with page parameter. simply populate your page links using them and call your fetchOrder function with their url when clicked.

Comment: Hi sir @MehrdadDehghani Can you give me an example , I'm newbie and trying to learn, its confusing to me I appreciate the help

Comment: Hi @aynber , can you please give me an example on how to do it, thank you so much